# Unable to download pdf from web application

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, webbrowser-control

Unable to download pdf from the [Web Application](https://www.greatertelugu.org/themencode-pdf-viewer-sc/?tnc_pvfw=ZmlsZT1odHRwczovL3d3dy5ncmVhdGVydGVsdWd1Lm9yZy93cC1jb250ZW50L3VwbG9hZHMvMjAxNy8wNS9tYWhhYmhhcmF0YW0tZnVsbC10ZWx1Z3UucGRmJnNldHRpbmdzPTAwMTExMTExMSZsYW5nPWVuLVVT#page=7&zoom=auto,-107,842). I'm using chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After complete browsing Use command CTRL+P , it navigate you print page here change the destination save as PDF and then it download for it

Please see snapshot[image: Here]

Comment: Oh great. Thank you

Comment: Glad it helps you